# Simulating friend classes in PHP

Tags: php, private, friend, private-members

I have a class `Foo` with a number of public and private methods. One of those methods is getting rather large, and I would like to fork it off into a separate class specifically for that purpose. Something like this:

```
<?php

class Foo
{
  //  ...

  public function doX( $a, $b )
  {
    $x = new FooXDoer;
    $x->foo = $this;
    return $x->run( $a, $b );
  }

  //  ...
}

class FooXDoer
{
  public $foo;

  public function run( $a, $b )
  {
    // ...
  }

  // ...
}
```

`FooXDoer` has access to `Foo`'s public methods and properties through `$this->foo`.

How can I give `FooXDoer` access to `Foo`'s private methods and properties, without making them public to the rest of the code which already uses `Foo`?

Should I create a separate class `FooPrivate` which has the private methods as public, and which `Foo` wraps, and then have `FooXDoer` reference that? What should `FooPrivate` be called?

Or is my approach completely wrong? How do you solve this problem in general?

Comment: It's pretty unclear (to me at least) what you're trying to do here. Could you use real-life examples?

Comment: If you want to seperate funtionality between classes make sure that the classes have their information. If function X relies on the data of object y and does manipulations on it I would suggest you keep the functionality in object y.

Comment: I'd say make 'em public, but put in comments to warn off other coders.  While you can probably build something that will programatically prevent access by other classes, it's not going to be pretty.

Comment: if you want to access private properties, you can pass them to the constructor of FooXDoe() . You can not do this for private methods however.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like [traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) solve your problem best in case you use PHP >= 5.4.

If not, I thought of the following solution:

```
class A {
    private static $allowedClasses = array('B');
    private $a = 1;

    public function __get($property) {
        $caller = debug_backtrace(false);
        if(!isset($caller[1]))
            throw new Exception('Bla bla');
        if(!in_array($caller[1]['class'], self::$allowedClasses))
            throw new Exception('Bla bla');
        return $this->$property;
    }

    public function testB() {
        $b = new B();
        $b->instA = $this;
        echo $b->getA();
    }

}

class B {
    public $instA;
    public function getA() {
        return $this->instA->a;
    }
}

class C {
    public function getA() {
        $instA = new A();
        return $instA->a;
    }
}

$a = new A();
$a->testB(); // Works ok;
$c = new C();
$c->getA(); // Throws exception here;
```

This code is definitely not a best practice :)  But since it is possible I put it here.

Comment: A correct, however hideous, solution to the problem. Could you briefly describe how traits could resolve this?

Comment: Traits have access to methods and properties of the class they're used in. So you can implement your large function in a trait and use all properties of your Foo class.

Comment: sure not best practice, and nothing for productive code, but somehow I like this...very creative use of language features

Comment: It like an access control for class properties. It's crazy but I like it!

Answer (score 2):

PHP has no friend class concept, from what I've read I wouldn't say it's a bad decision by the php designers...

IMHO, there is no general strategy, as the problem or question is too broad: there are too many factors to consider:

- how many private properties and methods of `Foo` are needed in `run()`?
- from an abstraction point of view: how closely is `run()` entangeled in `Foo`? Does it really "deserve" to be in an independent class?
- will you ever use `FooXDoer` outside of `Foo`?

**Two ideas for solutions:**

hand over the needed data from `foo` to `fooDoer`, either value for value or by implementing a `compileRunData()` on `Foo` that returns an array or an object

```
public function doX( $a, $b )
{
 $x = new FooXDoer;
 $workEnvironment = $this->compileRunData();
 $x->setEnvironment( $workEnvironment );
 $x->foo = $this;
 return $x->run( $a, $b );
}
```

or use inheritance, especially the concept of protected properties:

```
abstract class FooAbstract
{
 protected $_basicVar1;
 protected function basicMethod1(/*...*/) {
  //...
 }
 // ...
}

abstract class FooRunner extends FooAbstract
{
 protected $_runVar1;

 protected function runMethod1(/*...*/) {
  //...
 }

 public function run($a, $b) {
  // ...
 }
}

public class Domain_Model_Foo extends FooRunner 
{

}
```

edit: hey, SO didn't show me there was already an answer. Yea, thought about traits, too, but haven't used them until now so can't really comment on them

Comment: I think inheritance would be the best solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Below there is an easy-to-use function preventing a function from being used by classes not listed in "friendClass()". In the example, the "Item" object may be constructed only by "Foo" class. Otherwise, an exception is thrown.

```
    function friendClass($classNames){
            if(!is_array($classNames))
                $classNames = [$classNames];
            $trace = debug_backtrace();
            $called = $trace[1];
            $caller = $trace[2];
            $calledFunction =
                $called['class']."::".$called['function'];
            $callerFunction =
                $caller['class']."::".$caller['function'];
        
            if(!in_array($caller['class'], $classNames))
                throw new exception( 
                 "Unauthorized use of $calledFunction() by  $callerFunction()"
                );
        }
        
        class Item{
            function __construct(){
                friendClass('Foo'); // "Friend class" declaration
                echo "Item object created\n";
            }
        };
        
        class Foo{
            function caller(){
                $item = new Item();
            }
        };
        
        class Bar{
            function caller(){
                $item = new Item();
            }
        };
        
        $foo = new Foo();
        $bar = new Bar();
        $foo->caller(); //allowed
        $item = new Item(); // exception
        $bar->caller(); //exception
```